# Rrule from Datetime collection

Tags: php, recurrence, rrule

I'm making a recurrent activity calendar system and i'm facing an issue. My activity has a collection of Period items, which contain a StartedAt Datetime and an EndedAt Datetime.

A lot of libs allow me to convert my RRule from a string to Period-like items, but it seems that the reverse (Having multiple "DateTime-couples" converted to a RRule string) isn't common at all.

Any option about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A lot of libs allow me to convert my RRule from a string to Period-like items, but it seems that the reverse (Having multiple "DateTime-couples" converted to a RRule string) isn't common at all.

That's because it's not possible. A given RRule generates one and only one set of occurrences, but the opposite is not true - a given set of occurrences can be generated by a multitude of RRules.

In other words, it's impossible to know the exact rule that generated a collection of dates.

Comment: This was my believe. I mean, it's always possible to tinker something, but with high risks of mistakes.
Anyway, thank you.